# making a container fixed when immemdiate parent is scrolling but not fixed when body is scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed div and would like to keep it fixed so that when its parent is scrolled it stays as it is but when the parent's scroll is done and when the body scroll starts then the 'container in question' should start scrolling.

some thing like

```
<div id="fixedContainer">container in question</div>

#fixedContainer
{
background-color:#ddd;
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
left: 50%;
top: 0%;
margin-left: -100px; /*half the width*/
}
```

and then

```
<div style="height:300px;background-color:#bbb;overflow:scroll;">soeme div</div>
```

I have made a sample here
http://jsfiddle.net/tDpJB/

Thanks in advance for the help.
-Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a better idea to absolutely position the element *above* the scrolled container instead of trying to place it fixed inside? Would that emulate the effect you're looking for?

Comment: I believe absolute positioning would scroll the container no matter where the scroll is done, either in the parent element or in window but I'm looking for an effect where scroll event in parent would keep the effect of position fixed and scroll event in body would give absolute effect.